# Pydantic - Access default setting in the custom source definition

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I need pydantic to overwrite the current configs if there is any config in a specific API endpoint.

```
def json_config_settings_source(settings: BaseSettings) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """Load initial configs from configuration service."""
    __get_url = f"{Settings.config_url}/api/v4/{Settings.config_component}"
    response = requests.get(__get_url, headers={"Accept": "application/json"}, timeout=5)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    config_url: AnyUrl = "https://localhost:8080"
    config_component: str = "my-service"
    ...

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
        env_file_encoding = "utf-8"
        case_sensitive = False

        @classmethod
        def customise_sources(
            cls,
            init_settings: SettingsSourceCallable,
            env_settings: SettingsSourceCallable,
            file_secret_settings: SettingsSourceCallable,
        ) -> Tuple[SettingsSourceCallable, ...]:
            return env_settings, init_settings, file_secret_settings, json_config_settings_source
```

when i try to access `Settings.config_url` or `settings.config_url` from within the `json_config_settings_source` i get `AttributeError: type object 'Settings' has no attribute 'config_url'`.
Although when I use `settings.__fields__` the attributes are there.

is it a normal behavior and I have to access the attributes using `__fields__` or there is a better way?

Comment: How are you creating your settings object? That error is usually caused by a method being called _on the class_, and not on an object created from the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. The reason is that the settings source callables are all called *before* the underlying model `__init__` is called.

The settings sources basically construct the keyword arguments that are then used to initialize the settings model. ([Source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/env_settings.py#L39))

This means that no instance attributes (representing fields) are present at that point. So you'll have to use the `__fields__` class attribute:

```py
def json_config_settings_source(settings: BaseSettings) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    default_config_url = settings.__fields__["config_url"].default
    default_config_component = settings.__fields__["config_component"].default
    __get_url = f"{default_config_url}/api/v4/{default_config_component}"
    ...
```